# Mysql: divide result by column change

Tags: mysql

I have a table like these

```
date - name - val
16/02 - Rossi - 5
16/02 - Zingaro - 8
18/02 - Beniamino - 4
18/02 - Bosso - 2
```

Is possible with a query to get result like this?

```
16/02
Rossi - 5
Zingaro - 8
18/02
Beniamino - 4
Bosso - 2
```

Or I must do the query and then work with if/else ?

Comment: It's possible, but it makes much more sense to store the results in another column when creating the records if that is practical to do. Storing those results will allow you to work with them much more efficiently using MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple select query can be like

```
select name,val froom table where date=&date
```

so with this you will get all the record with name & val for particular date.

Now question is no one is going to write query for each date.

So simply you can fetch all distinct date from your table with query

```
select DISTINCT date from table name
```

Now what remains is that you need to write a **procedure** which will have a loop and will take output of ditinct date as iterator and for each iteration fire select query for name & val.